# How to download packages from private repository with puppet?

Tags: apt, package-management, puppet

I've set up my own apt repository to serve some `.deb` packages over LAN and I've set up my puppet configuration to install these packages.

If I use `apt-get install` to download the package it works fine, but when I run my puppet manifest, it throws this error when it tries to install:

```
Error: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install cuda-repo-l4t-r19.2' returned 100: Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cuda-repo-l4t-r19.2
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/424 MB of archives.
After this operation, 426 MB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  cuda-repo-l4t-r19.2
E: There are problems and -y was used without --force-yes

Error: /Stage[main]/Main/Package[cuda-repo-l4t-r19.2]/ensure: change from absent to present failed: Execution of '/usr/bin/apt-get -q -y -o DPkg::Options::=--force-confold install cuda-repo-l4t-r19.2' returned 100: Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cuda-repo-l4t-r19.2
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/424 MB of archives.
After this operation, 426 MB of additional disk space will be used.
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  cuda-repo-l4t-r19.2
E: There are problems and -y was used without --force-yes
```

I'm not sure exactly where the problem is; puppet? My repository? Something else?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it was because my repository wasn't authenticated. I got around this by adding allowing apt to download from unauthenticated repositories, and did this by creating the following file using puppet:

```
  file { "/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99auth":       
    owner     => root,
    group     => root,
    content   => "APT::Get::AllowUnauthenticated yes;",
    mode      => 644;
  }
```